# Using recalc function to change a field if item has weight

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I currently have a recalc function that resets the shipping cost field if a line item has changed, but I really only need to do that if the item has a weight. How do I retrieve the weight of the changed line item?

Here's what I currently have:

```
function recalc(){  
    nlapiSetFieldValue('shippingcost', '0.00');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`recalc` is fired *only* when a change to a line item affects the *Total* of the transaction, and as such, may not be a reliable event for what you want to accomplish.

I would recommend against using `validateLine` as that event should be used to determine whether the new value for a field is valid.

I would advise you to use `fieldChanged` for responding to a field value that has changed. Something like:

```
function fieldChanged(type, name, linenum) {
    if (type == 'item') {
        if (name == 'item') {
            handleItemChange(linenum);
        }
    }
}

function handleItemChange(linenum) {
    var itemWeight = parseFloat(nlapiGetFieldValue('item', 'weight', linenum)) || 0;
    if (itemWeight > 0) {
        nlapiSetFieldValue('shippingcost', 0);
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider the `postSourcing` event instead of `fieldChanged`, depending on which fields should actually trigger this logic.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I will give that a try. For some reason, I was under the impression that fieldChanged didn't fire when a line item changed and recalc had to be used for that purpose. Thanks!

Comment: So I may be missing something, but this isn't working as expected. The fieldChange event is fired when an item is added to the list, but when you change a field on the list (like item quantity) it doesn't. Thoughts?

Comment: The event should definitely be fired no matter what field gets modified. The event gets fired once focus leaves the field you are changing (e.g. hitting Tab or clicking on the next field). If you wrote your code exactly as it is above, then `handleItemChange` only gets invoked when the `item` field is changed. If you want to call `handleItemChange` no matter what column gets changed on the item sublist, just remove the if check for `name`

Answer (score 2):

Small segue, recalc doesn't give you a way to get the current line of the sublist, you'd need to loop through the whole sublist anytime a single line was changed.

Try validateLine, something like:

```
function validateLine(listType){

    //To get the item weight, you could create a 
    //custom transaction column field that sourced the item weight.

    if(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue(listType,'custcolitemWeight') > 0){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('shippingcost','0.00')
    }

    //or you could source directly from the item record using nlapiLookupField  
    // Depending on your use case either could be  appropriate

    if(nlapiLookupField('item',nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue(listType,'item'),'weight')){
        nlapiSetFieldValue('shippingcost','0.00')
    }
    //you *need* to return true with the validate* event functions. 
    return true;
}
```

This (untested) example only handles line additions.  If users are allowed to remove items, you'll need to implement a similar validateDelete that also reverts your changes.

Comment: This is what I was trying originally with the recalc function, but as you stated, it doesn't work with recalc. Awesome, thank you!

Comment: I can't comment on @egrubaugh360's answer(since i don't have enough rep), but their solution is at least as good and the commentary about not using `validateLine` unless you _need_ to be able to invalidate a change is definitely reasonable.